# Wait for Runnables to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, java-8, runnable

I have implemented a programm in javafx which dynamically generates an input mask and generates a Word-document after a button click on that mask.

I define in an db-table which input fields are available in this mask.
Now I'm adding support for custom procedures which are executed on specific states of my program (onFocusLost of an field,onChange,...)
Wich works perfect.

Now I'm stuck at the onGenerate execution.

When I render the mask, I hold a List of `Runnable`s to store my actions which should be executed on generation (At the render time i know which action should be executed. At Generation time i would have to read all the data in again. So I thought I save the action with `FunctionalInterface`. And I need no inputParameter and no ReturnValue ... so i ended up with `Runnable`)

```
TextField tf = ...;
String s = ...;

actionsBeforeGenerate.add(() -> {
                tf.setText(s);
            });
```

So now, if I press the generate button, I do the following:

```
private void startGenerate(){
 //main.getActionsBeforeGenerate() == List<Runnable>
 main.getActionsBeforeGenerate().forEach(action -> action.run());

 generateWordDocument(); 

}
```

The text is set to the node correctly, BUT after the document is generated.

How can I change the textField BEFORE my generationLogic starts?

If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask for it.

**EDIT:**

I think I've found the solution for my problem:

```
private void startGenerate(){

Task<Boolean> task = new Task<Boolean>() {          

@Override
public Boolean call() throws Exception {
    main.getActionsBeforeGenerate().forEach(action -> action.run());
    ....
    generateWordDocument();
    ....
    return Boolean.TRUE;
  }
};



Thread thread = new Thread(task);
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
}
```

Now I have the new values textField values available in `generateWordDocument()`

Comment: Let me express my understading; you want that your generate-logic is started after all actions in getActionsBeforeGenerate() list got run?

Comment: @UlukBiy yes. The mask should be updated before my document is generated (now the actions get executed, but it has no effect, because the textfields hold the new value after the document is finished and not before ... so the new values are not in the generated document)

Comment: What do you mean by "my document is generated"? Is it regular JavaFX (fxml) app? Even manipulating the scene graph later, it will get the changes. I mean maybe you don't need to wait the runnables to finish.

Comment: please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @UlukBiy the program generates a word-document (docx). Yes, its a regular javaFx app.

Comment: you might (or not, depending on whether the controls are already part of the scene graph) have a threading bomb in your solution snippet